# open terminal in IntelliJ IDEA and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have set the shell path to `/usr/sbin` but it does not open the terminal in  IntelliJ IDEA is an IDE for Java,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write: **/bin/bash, /bin/zsh, /home/user/myOwnShell** etc
just write path to file no to directory.